# Formula to sum up formatted cells with commas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I'd like to sum up all the formatted `D2:D6` cells and print this info in total

```
---------------------------
D2  | January  |  1,000   |
---------------------------
D3  | February |  2,000   |
---------------------------
D4  | March    |  3,000   |
---------------------------
D5  | April    |    400   |
---------------------------
D6  | May      |    500   |
---------------------------
D7  | Total    |  6,900   |
---------------------------
```

I tried to apply this formula, but it gave me an error:

```
=SUM(VALUE(REPLACE(D2:D6;FIND(",",D2:D6;1),1;"")))
```

Comment: Try `SUMPRODUCT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sum the range.

If the range is not numbers, but text that looks like numbers, the question is: why is that so? Why would a number be turned into text?

- To insert a thousand comma?? That can be done with number formatting without destroying the number data type.
- the data was downloaded like that from a report? Use Power Query to load the report and clean up the data in Power Query. Then you can use simple Excel formulas.

If none of the above are viable options, the final resort can be a formula, like

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBSTITUTE(D2:D6,",","")+0))
```

Your sample formula suggests that your regional settings use the semicolon to separate parameters in Excel, so you need this:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((SUBSTITUTE(D2:D6;",";"")+0))
```

**Edit:** Another variant that will not break if a cell in the range is blank or contains text that cannot be converted to a number:

```
=SUMProduct(IF(ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(D2:D6,",","")+0),SUBSTITUTE(D2:D6,",","")+0,0))
```

the semicolon version:

```
=SUMProduct(IF(ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(D2:D6;",";"")+0);SUBSTITUTE(D2:D6;",";"")+0;0))
```

With this construct you can also use Sum() instead of SumProduct() but note that for non 365 versions of Excel the Sum() variant the formula needs to be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Cleaning the data up with Power Query might be a lot easier than using formulas like that for simple calculations like totaling numbers.